# Force Glassfish to bind to a network interface

Tags: glassfish

We are using Glassfish on multi homed servers and I would like to force Glassfish just to use one interface.

I updated domain.xml by

- substituting every occurrence of 0.0.0.0 by the IP address
- everywhere a port was mentioned without an address `address=<IP>` was added
- every `host=localhost` was substituted with `host=<IP>`

After starting Glassfish several listeners are still listening on every available IP address:

- 3820: I tried to specify an address but the option is ignored

  ```
   <iiop-listener port="3820" id="SSL" address="<IP>" security-enabled="true">
  ```
- 3920: same as above

  ```
  <iiop-listener port="3920" id="SSL_MUTUALAUTH" address="127.0.0.1" security-enabled="true">
  ```

  has no effect
- 7776: no idea

The next listeners use some dynamically generated ports

- 53491
- 53495
- 53496
- 53497

Now my question:

- is there a way to make sure Glassfish will be using one and just one network interface?
- if this cannot be achieved with Glassfish is there a way on a Linux system to trick an application to see only one interface?

Comment: Hi, the best way would be to ask in the users mailinglist. http://java.net/projects/glassfish/lists/users/archive